# Errors Using langchain_core.agents.utils.function_calling.convert_to_openai_function in Python

Tags: python, openai-api, nameerror

I'm working on a Python project where I need to use specific functions from a library called langchain_core to convert tools into OpenAI-compatible functions. However, I'm encountering a NameError when I attempt to run my code.

Problem:
Here is the code snippet that's causing the issue:

```
tools = [GetCurrentWeatherTool()]
#functions = [format_tool_to_openai_function(tool_name) for tool_name in tools]
functions = [langchain_core.agents.utils.function_calling.convert_to_openai_function(tool_name) for tool_name in tools]
```

And the error I receive is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[16], line 3
      1 tools = [GetCurrentWeatherTool()]
      2 #functions = [format_tool_to_openai_function(tool_name) for tool_name in tools]
----> 3 functions = [langchain_core.agents.utils.function_calling.convert_to_openai_function(tool_name) for tool_name in tools]

Cell In[16], line 3, in <listcomp>(.0)
      1 tools = [GetCurrentWeatherTool()]
      2 #functions = [format_tool_to_openai_function(tool_name) for tool_name in tools]
----> 3 functions = [langchain_core.agents.utils.function_calling.convert_to_openai_function(tool_name) for tool_name in tools]

NameError: name 'langchain_core' is not defined
```

I am using Python 3.9,  Langchain 0.1.12, and openai  1.10.0  in a virtual environment.
I have verified that langchain_core is properly installed in my environment.
I tried to see if I needed to import any additional module or if there was any missing dependency, but I couldn't find clear information regarding this.
What I've Tried:
Ensuring all necessary packages are installed and up-to-date.
Searching for specific langchain_core documentation for this use case but found no similar examples.
Commenting and uncommenting different parts of the code to isolate the problem.
Question:
How can I resolve the NameError and ensure that langchain_core is correctly defined and accessible in my code? Is there a specific import or setup I am missing?

I would appreciate any guidance or code examples that could help me move forward with this issue.

Comment: Make sure you pip installed langchain_core and did an import langchain_core in y our code.